# Run function after directive is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

Currently I was trying to run a function that handles resizing after a directive is loaded. Always, the function runs before the content is loaded in the directive therefore it doesn't resize properly.

Here is a snippet of the code that I am using:

```
    $scope.myToggleFunctionForDirective() = function(){
       $scope.changeableVariable = !$scope.changeableVariable
       myResizeFunction();
    }
    window.myResizeFunction = function (){           
       //do something
    }
```

The html looks something like this

```
    <button ng-click="myToggleFunctionForDirective()"></button>
    <my-directive ng-if="changeableVariable"></div>
```

The directive contains some async calls from the server.

Any idea as to how to wait for the directive to finish loading and then apply the function to the content created by the directive, are welcome.

I tried looking over $broadcast and $emit, but for some reason it does not seem to work for me.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT1: I updated the code to reflect more on what I have in my project.

Comment: How about changing `ng-if` to `ng-show`?

Comment: @Egan ng-show does not reset the scope from the directive if the toggle variable is set to false, unfortunately.

Answer (score 0):

Why not have a controller in the directive, and making the button from there?

```
angular.module('myApp')
    .directive('myToggleButton', myToggleButton);

/* @ngInject */
function myToggleButton() {
    var directive = {
        restrict: 'E',
        bindToController: true,
        controller: myToggleController,
        // your other directive pieces, scope, restrict, etc
    };
    return directive;
}

function myToggleController() {
    var vm = this;
    vm.reSize = reSize;

    function reSize() {           
        //do something
    }
}
```

In your button:

```
<my-toggle-button data-ng-click="vm.reSize()"></my-toggle-button>
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. The special resize function works regardless regardless if the directive is there or not and it handles a different div from the page. When the directive loads, it resizes that particular div and the directive. Including the resize function in the directive will stop the normal div from resizing itself.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve the situation by setting variable on the $rootScope and adding a watcher for it in my page. In the directive I set that particular variable to be true and in the page, the variable is set to false once some conditions are met. Hopefully this will help others solve the issue.

```
//app.js file:
$rootScope.myVariable = false;

//directive file
$rootScope.myVariable = true

//main page file:
$rootScope.$watch ('myVariable', function (){
   if($rootScope.myVariable){
       myResizeFunction();
   }
});

$scope.myToggleFunctionForDirective() = function(){
   $scope.changeableVariable = !$scope.changeableVariable
   if($scope.changeableVariable) {
      $rootScope.myVariable = false
   }
}
```